# If $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$, and $\frac{dy}{dt}=4$, find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ when $(x,y,z) = (2,2,1)$

Tags: calculus

If $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$, and $\frac{dy}{dt}=4$, find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ when $(x,y,z) = (2,2,1)$

help with this would be so appreciated... Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating with respect to t

$$2x\frac{dx}{dt} + 2y\frac{dy}{dt} + 2z\frac{dz}{dt} = 0$$
 then put x = 2, y = 2,z = 1 , $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 5,\frac{dy}{dt} = 4 $$ in above equation to get the answer of $$\frac{dz}{dt}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$z=\sqrt {9-(x^2+y^2)}$$ $$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$$